# Count amount of matches within a subquery to order the query by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the amount of matches within a subquery to order the results by.

Query I am trying:

```
SELECT recipes.*, (SELECT COUNT(ingredient_id) FROM recipes WHERE ingredient_id IN(1,3))            AS ingredient_matches 
FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN ingredients 
ON recipes.id = ingredients.recipe_id 
INNER JOIN ingredients_available 
ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients_available.id
GROUP BY recipes.id 
ORDER BY ingredient_matches DESC;
```

Database structure:

```
recipes:
id, name
ingredients:
id, recipe_id, ingredient_id
ingredients_available:
id, name
tags:
id, recipe_id, tag_id
tags_available:
id, name
```

The query below works but I want to be able to have access ingredients that are not matched so I can say they need them if that makes sense?

```
SELECT recipes.*, COUNT(ingredients.id) AS ingredient_matches 
FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN ingredients 
ON recipes.id = ingredients.recipe_id 
INNER JOIN ingredients_available 
ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients_available.id
WHERE ingredient_id IN (1, 5) 
GROUP BY recipes.id 
ORDER BY ingredient_matches DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f9ef/15

Was the desired result. It is because I didn't make sure recipes_id = ingredients.recipe_id within the subquery.

Comment: Sorry I had been busy to follow up on this. Glad you were able to solve, this was a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work?:

```
SELECT recipes.*, COUNT(ingredients.id) AS ingredient_matches 
FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN ingredients 
ON recipes.id = ingredients.recipe_id 
LEFT JOIN ingredients_available 
ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients_available.id
WHERE ingredient_id IN (1, 5) 
GROUP BY recipes.id 
ORDER BY ingredient_matches DESC;
```

Comment: No see for example:

`SELECT recipes.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredients.id, ":" ,  ingredients_available.name) AS all_ingredients, COUNT(ingredients.id)     AS ingredient_matches 
FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN ingredients 
ON recipes.id = ingredients.recipe_id 
LEFT JOIN ingredients_available 
ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients_available.id
WHERE ingredient_id IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY recipes.id 
ORDER BY ingredient_matches DESC;`

I still cannot access all_ingredients for a recipe, only the ingredients which match 1,5

Comment: would it be possible to get a sql fiddle to test these out? It should make things easier as the queries are a bit long...

Comment: why do you need the condition of matching the ingredient_id in (1,5)?

Comment: Because I wish to order the results by the recipes with the most ingredient matches

Comment: sure, but you can still do that without that condition

Comment: Could you a provide an example?